# latex hyperref form choice menu finding a way to make the box of the list for choosing wider than the field of the ChoiceMenu

Tags: latex

I'm using MikTeX LaTeX and I want to create a form with a choice menu of the hyperref package. I was wondering if there is a way to make the box of the list for choosing wider than the field of the choice menu? Does someone know a way? The approach present here includes that the width of the choice menu field specified in the parameter is kept, even though the text of the items in the list are much longer.

Here is a working minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\hide}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}{#1}}

% begin document
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
      \begin{tabular}{l}
            \mbox{\ChoiceMenu[combo, name=test_choice, width=4cm]{Choice field:}{short 1, \hide{this is a very long sentence leading to a much greater field width than specified}}}
      \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The drop down to select one of the choices is not done by latex, but by your pdf viewer. Use a suitable viewer to see the choices in full width.

Preview.app:

[image]

Skim.app:

[image]